# I can't fill path selected with pen tool help!

Tags: adobe-photoshop

am making a cartoon image so up until now after I select a colour and a path with pen tool I press Control + enter and Alt + delete to fill the section but now I when I press it nothing happens I tried everything nothing happened. Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the pen tool, right-click on the shape and choose "make selection".

[image]

Then you can use your alt + delete shortcut.